# Error in Calling Procedure in Oracle 11 g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new for oracle and facing below issue while calling the stored procedure in Oracle.

Error: 
*Bind Variable "ERROR_MSG" is NOT DECLARED

anonymous block completed*

1)
Calling of the stored Procedure

```
DECLARE 

  XMLDATA VARCHAR2(200);

  P_YEAR_ID NUMBER;

  USER_ID NUMBER;

  ERROR_MSG NVARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN

  XMLDATA := NULL;

  P_YEAR_ID := NULL;

  USER_ID := NULL;

  PK_ADMIN.P_SAVE_ROLLUP_LPF_FAC(

    XMLDATA => XMLDATA,

    P_YEAR_ID => P_YEAR_ID,

    USER_ID => USER_ID,

    ERROR_MSG => ERROR_MSG

  );



     :ERROR_MSG := ERROR_MSG;
    --rollback; 

END;
```

2)
Definition of the Procedure:

Below procedure is in a Package

```
PROCEDURE P_SAVE_ROLLUP_LPF_FAC(xmlData IN VARCHAR2,p_year_id number,user_id 

number,error_msg OUT nocopy NVARCHAR2) AS

  X SYS.XMLTYPE;

    NEW_BU_ID NUMBER;

  BEGIN

    X := sys.xmltype.createXML(xmlData);

    BEGIN     

      //Here is the logic for processing of the XML

  END;
```

Comment: can you change this : `:ERROR_MSG := ERROR_MSG;` this to `ERROR_MSG := ERROR_MSG;`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ersin it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart what @Ersin Guelbahar Suggested, I would like you to make few more changes to the way you call the procedure:

```
DECLARE 

  XMLDATA VARCHAR2(200):= NULL;

  P_YEAR_ID NUMBER:=NULL;

  USER_ID NUMBER :=NULL;

  ERROR_MSG NVARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN

 /*****No need to assign at sepearate step. You can decalre and assign*****
  --XMLDATA := NULL;

  --P_YEAR_ID := NULL;

  --USER_ID := NULL; ********************/

  PK_ADMIN.P_SAVE_ROLLUP_LPF_FAC(

    XMLDATA => XMLDATA,

    P_YEAR_ID => P_YEAR_ID,

    USER_ID => USER_ID,

    ERROR_MSG => ERROR_MSG

  );

     ERROR_MSG := ERROR_MSG;
    --rollback; 

END;
```